# Plot until a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I am using MATLAB but I think Python code would do as well after being adapted to the MATLAB syntax.

I have 2 vectors:x and y.

- x has 102 values
- y has 124 values

Tried;
plot(x,y:len(x)) but it didn't work giving the error that x and y are not the same length.

I want to do something like plot(x,y) but until 102 values. Is this possible?

Comment: cant you just chop y off at 102 before plotting?

Comment: `plot(x,y[:len(x)])` or this maybe

Comment: The thing is that I also have other files where I have hundreds of thousands of values, so I think i can't I'm afraid. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Are you sure that x is one-dimensional (#1 error I get in these problems)? In Python ```plot(x,y[:len(x)])``` should work

Comment: @CannedScientist actually It's not 1D, that's the issue, but I know the number of values. I am using MATLAB instead of Python, but I am adapting the Code from Python's syntax

Comment: @Nytro What kind of plot are you trying to produce? Is a scatter plot okay?

Comment: @CannedScientist, yes the scatter would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try plotting each point separately:

**Python**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(range(102)) #102 values
y = list(range(124)) #124 values

for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.scatter(x = x[i], y = y[i]) #plots each the point on the ax at the specified spot
plt.show()
```

Here is a helpful link on [matplotlib Axes in Python](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html).